# Hello with a for loop with a nested foreach

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, foreach-loop-container

I have the following php,

```
 <ul>
<?php $count = count($products); ?>
            <?php for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++ ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php foreach ($products as $k => $v) : ?>
                    <div>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/images/products/<?php echo $v['product_image_small']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $v['product_title']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $v['product_id']; ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
           </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </ul>
```

What I wanting to achieve is to create an `li` nested with up to 6 `div`s, and once there are 6 `div`s I want to create a new `li`. The code above is currently creating the following,

```
<li>  
<div></div>  
<div></div>  
<div></div>  
<div></div>  
</li>
```

...however there should only be 2 `div`s in my `li` due to the size of the products array.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of $count? 'echo $count'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping 2 x 2 times, instead of 2, as both loops are nested. Use only `for` or `foreach`.

To answer your real question: how about something like ...

```
echo "<li>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
   // ...

   if ($i % 6 == 5)
     echo "</li><li>";    
}
echo "</li>";
```

Comment: Note that this is just a code example. You will still need to test the edge cases (0, 5, 6) and see if an empty `<li></li>` would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your lines:

```
 <ul>
<?php $count = count($products); ?>
            <?php for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++ ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php foreach ($products as $k => $v) : ?>
                    <?php if($i % 4 == 0) echo '</li><li>'; ?>
                    <div>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/images/products/<?php echo $v['product_image_small']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $v['product_title']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $v['product_id']; ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
           </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </ul>
```

Hope that helps